# StreamWriter not working Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Got a bit of a strange issue with a bit of code in Xamarin Forms:

```
public void GetSettings()
{
    var assembly = typeof(SettingsPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FishBike_GPS.config.txt");
    try
    {
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)) //load current settings from the config text file
        {
            configText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        CurrentRentalSetting = Int32.Parse(configText);
        stream.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        configText = "Error reading file!";
    }

}
public void SetSettings()
{
    var assembly = typeof(SettingsPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("FishBike_GPS.config.txt");
    try
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream)) //save current settings from the config text file
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine("test");
        }
        stream.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    {
        configText = "Error writing to file!";
        infoLabel2.Text = configText;
    }

}
```

The read function using streamreader works perfectly fine and reads the file displaying it ect, however although I'm using the same setup for the stream the streamwriter does not. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: wondering it its set to read only, not sure how I would check though

Comment: ??? You can not write/overwrite an embedded resource, it is a read-only blob within the assembly

Comment: then is there a non-read online resource type I can use? How would I set up such a file?

Comment: You can write it to the file system of the device : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/#Saving_and_Loading_Files

Comment: cheers, will try it out

Comment: Are you trying to write to an asset that you included in the project? If so it wont work. You can only read from asset files you cant edit them. (They are read only)

Comment: Thanks, I found that out in the end. I ended up using the application properties instead, that works fine.